# Could we construct a Lorentz-invariant Planck-length like this?

Tags: special-relativity, beyond-the-standard-model

The planck length is defined as $l_P = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar G}{c^3}}$. This is a Lorentz invariant length. So even when I look at an observer moving close to lightspeed, this length should have this value. In the moving frame, all distance seem smaller though.

Can we solve this by pushing the PL into a tiny 3D Planck-sized hypersphere, perpendicular to the three large dimensions we live in? The direction perpendicular to motion isn't influenced so the Planck length stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is “no”.

> The planck length is defined as $l_P = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar G}{c^3}}$. This is a Lorentz invariant length.

This is not a Lorentz invariant length. A Lotentz invariant length would be a length where if an object has that length then all frames agree it has that length.

Special relativity itself has no particular length scale, so the Planck length is subject to length contraction just like any other length. This means that, according to special relativity alone, different frames will disagree about the length of a Planck length sized object, just as they would about other size objects.

Now, although SR itself does not have a length scale, a theory of matter does. More importantly, at the Planck scale the Lorentz transform may not be physically valid. So the mathematical fact that the Planck length is not Lorentz invariant does not imply that it is not a physically relevant length scale.

> Can we solve this by pushing the PL into a tiny 3D Planck-sized hypersphere, perpendicular to the three large dimensions we live in? The direction perpendicular to motion isn't influenced so the Planck length stays the same.

None of this would change how the Lorentz transform behaves in the three large spatial dimensions.

Comment: But what about the perpendicular lengths, or volume? Wont it stay constant?